# Reducibility of Representation.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I was studying the Reducible Representation of groups.
$$\phi: g\to GL(V)$$
where $V$ is a vector space and $g$ is the group representation.
Say S is an invariant subspace of V under the group operations. Hence,
$$\phi_g(s)\in S \ \forall \ g \in G, \ \forall s\ \in S$$
Write $v$ a element in $V$ as
$$v = s+s'$$
where $s'$ belongs to the complement of S.
If we write v in the block form,
$$v = \left[\begin{array}{l}s\\ s'\end{array}\right]$$
Should the vector subspace s and s have a dimension less than V here?
Then the representation matrix can be written as
$$\phi_g(v) = \begin{bmatrix} \phi_1 & \phi_2 \\ \phi_3 & \phi_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} s\\ s'\end{bmatrix}$$
And now, by stating that $s$ is an invariant subspace of $V$. They put $\phi_3$ to be zero. I didn't get this point. How?

Comment: You didn't introduce $g_3$. Do you mean $\phi_3$?

Comment: @joriki Yes. Sorry For the type. I am correcting that.

Comment: What is your context, that you can say "_the_ complement of $S$"? Do you mean "_a_ complement"?

Comment: @paulgarrett V-S, the complement of S.

Comment: I don't think you want _set_ complement, but a _vectorspace_ complement...